# Распространенность Java-апплетов

Tags: java

Насколько распространено сейчас использование апплетов Java и есть ли смысл глубоко вникать в них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Распространённость почти нулевая. Но вникнуть я считаю что нужно. Во-первых, есть ряд вещей, которые через апплет можно сделать лучше, чем, например, во флеше из-за бОльшей производительности. Во-вторых, в сущности там особо вникать не во что: другой главный класс, нежели у обычного Swing-приложения, есть входные параметры (от браузера) и есть связь между апплетом и Java-скрипт страницы-контейнера. Поняв эти три несложные вещи можно считать, что вы глубоко вникли в них.

Кроме того, некоторые недостатоки апплетов постепенно уходят. Например, время старта виртуальной машины снизилось в разы за последние пару лет. Кроме того, многочисленные попытки сделать JavaFX так или иначе обернутся успехом и что-нибудь да будет в арсенале в конце концов. Так что я считаю, что апплеты всё ещё не стоит списывать со счетов.

Comment: Еще один вопрос. Можно ли создавать интерфейс апплета на основе Swing?

Comment: Да. Именно на свинге интерфейс для аплетов и создается. У Брюса Эккеля в его книге "Философия Java" есть даже пример, который позволяет очень быстро переключатся с апплетной версии на десктопную

Comment: сложно тут не вспомнить про Minecraft =)

Answer (score 3):

> Распространённость почти нулевая.

Я бы не был так категоричен, да технология не массовая, но в проприетарных системах распространена причем так неплохо распространена.

Апплеты прижились среди биржевых брокеров и всяких разных высоконагруженных графикой онлайн системах. В частности аналоги знаменитых [терминалов Блумберга](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomberg_Terminal) (это тот самый монитор, который всем нам показывают по телику когда рассказывают про биржу) обычно на простых писишках реализуются через апплеты. Типичный пример [здесь](http://www.stockapplets.com/)

Answer (score 2):

> Еще один вопрос. Можно ли создавать интерфейс апплета на основе Swing?
> Можно.

Answer (score 2):

Изучайте, не бойтесь. Если вы не встречаете аплетов в разных контактах и онлайн играх, это еще не значит, что они не распространены. Очень много корпоративных систем используют джаву не только для сервер-сайд приложений, но и для создания интерфейса пользователя.

По слухам, JavaFX летом должны внедрить в состав официальной JRE. Так что советую потрогать и ее.

И запомните, любая изученная технология не может быть изученная совсем напрасно. Зачастую, новое базируется каким-то образом на старом. Если вы разберетесь как работает одно - поумнее и сможете разобраться как работает другое.

Comment: когда-то были кружки радиолюбителей, а с телевизорами шли принципиальные схемы, кто бы мог подумать, что сейчас с отверткой в 42" плазму лезет только ребенок, что бы его "починить" =)

Comment: Те, кто интересовали электроникой и не перестали интересоваться, сейчас себе работу и увлечения найдут.